# XCode 13.3 - iPhone 11 - iOS 15.4 - Image Assets - Background Image not loading

Tags: objective-c, uiimageasset, xcode13.3, iphone11, ios-15.4

I am having an image assets used for loading the background image in my iOS application. The image assets contains background images that provides support for **2x, 3x, 2x Retina 4, 2x Retina HD 4.7", 3x iPhone X/iPhone Xs, 3x iPhone Xs Max and 2x iPhone XR**.

When i run my iOS application using **XCode 13.3 on iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro and iPhone 11 Pro Max then the background image is not loading instead a white colour background is getting displayed**.

When i try to run the iOS application using **XCode 13.3 on iPhone 12 or any other Simulator devices (other than iPhone 11 family) then the background image is getting loaded perfectly**.

Can you please suggest on how to fix the **background image loading issue getting occurred only in iPhone 11 having iOS 15.4 version**?